# Is each activity in android having its own context? What is the scenario with multiple activities in single application

Tags: android, android-context

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android) link to understand context in the android. I still have one question that does each activity have its own context?. Please consider i am an android learner in beginning level.

Comment: just create a constant activity variable and override it every time a new activity is created or recreated. usually done in onCreate() method

Comment: Activity is context itself!

Answer (score 6):

> I still have one question that does each activity have its own context?

Each `Activity` *is* its own `Context`. [`Activity` is a Java class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html); it inherits from `Context`:

[image: Activity inheritance tree]